# Why do hotel names often break the “adjective-first” rule?

Tags: adjectives, nouns, proper-nouns

In English, we generally say the adjective first, then the noun it describes. Many or most hotel names, however, are called “hotel” then followed by an adjective. Such as “Hotel Hayden” and “Hotel Green,” as opposed to “Hayden Hotel” and “Green Hotel.” Why?

Comment: Names such as "Hotel Majestic" might be influenced by French word order (where adjective often follows noun), on the assumption that the French are sophisticated or associated with fine food. There is also the practice of putting the name second with some geographical features (Mount Snowdon, River Thames, Lake Geneva). There are also some British castles e.g. [Castle Dore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castle_Dore), and place names like Castle Douglas.

Comment: I'd guess that it is the place and castle names are from the Norman-French influence as that language used (and Modern French still uses) post-positional adjectives. Hotels probably used this French form to add sophistication.

Comment: @StuartF Why are you putting answers in comments? Please post an answer.

Comment: @Greybeard Why are you putting answers in comments? Please post an answer.

Comment: @jsw29 Why are you putting answers in comments? Please post an answer.

Comment: _Hotel_ used to be regarded as a French loanword (people talked about _an hotel_, with a silent 'h'), so there is some logic to using French word order - but, as Rosie F says in her answer, it's not the case that 'most' hotels use it.

Comment: @tchrist - this cannot be an answer as I have absolutely no proof or authority that states that this is so. It seems to me to be very likely, but that is about the level of it.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that just as Norman words (pork) implied a higher status than Saxon (pig), the French-style postpositive (Hotel Splendide) is seen as being classier than say 'the _Splendid_ Hotel'. But it's just an educated guess; I have to echo Greybeard here.

Comment: @Greybeard You mean like the proof and authority contained within the two answers already provided?

Comment: @jsw29 Let’s please not let the “Perfect” be the enemy of the “Good Enough to Put in the Answer Box”, shall we? For my part I cannot but imagine that—barring me naïvely overestimating your own intuition, knowledge, resources, and skill—with scarcely more effort than it took you to write your 89‑word comment, you could have fairly easily put your ‘hints’ together into a suitable answer little less ‘self-contained’ than the 53‑ and 76‑word answers so far received.

Comment: @tchrist. Yes - although they were post-positional answers. They are both making a link that cannot be shown to be there. The requirement for authority in answers is somewhat crippling but I can see (sometimes) the point of it.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, the rest of the hotel's name is not an adjective (unless Green Hotel was intended to describe the hotel as being green).

I picked some true adjectives and did Google NGram comparisons of the two word-orders. Grand Hotel is far more popular than Hotel Grand; Royal Hotel is far more popular than Hotel Royal. A trouble with testing your "Hotel Green" example is that there will be false matches, e.g. "green hotel carpet".

Answer (score 1):

Two potential reasons:

1. Names like “Hotel Hayden” are not necessarily interpreted as phrases composed of a noun + an adjective, they can be seen as appositions, like "Mount Fuji" or "President Biden".
2. In French, the language we get the word "hotel" from, specifying modifiers come after the noun more often than in English.